# Verify IP address?

Tags: bash, ip, ping

I need to write a script in which I have to verify if an IP destination respond (read from keyboard). 
I supposed I have to use **ping**, but I'm not sure how.

Comment: It's unclear what your specific problem is. Do you just need help understanding how to write a `bash` script in general? You should then check online for a tutorial. Or do you now know how to deal with the output of `ping` when you call it from a script?

Comment: I know how  to write a bash script, I don't know how to write one to check that^ . Like how do I use the ping command to solve that problem?

Comment: Run `ping` from a prompt and see what it does when you give it an address that exists and what it does when the address is not a valid destination. You could write your script to check for key pieces of the output to determine if the destination exists.

Comment: I guess the simple test can be done this way: echo "IP: "; read a; echo $a; ping $a -q -c 1 | grep '0% packet loss' with some better postprocessing.

Comment: Note that "pinging" a host **only** tests that it (or something) responds to the ping.  The fact that it responds doesn't mean that a service on the host will work.  Conversely, you may still be able to connect to service in the case that the host doesn't respond to ping.  It all depends on how the target host + network + firewalls have been configured.

Answer (score 0):

To learn about the **ping** command, you may execute the command

```
man ping
```

or the command

```
ping --help
```

After executing the **ping** command in your script, you will need to process its return value and/or its output, somehow. Honza gave you a few commands that can be what you need, although you may want to do it differently, for several normal reasons.